# How to highlight parenthesis () and the text within it IF it contain specific words or symbol using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to highlight the text within a parenthesis ONLY if it contains the words "**RSVP**" and a section symbol "**§**".

So far I have this but I can't make it to work:
`\([^\]()*(?:USCS|§)[^\]()*)`

My goal is to target BOTH the parenthesis and the text inside.. for example:

(dog) (cat) (RSVP random text)

It should only highlight `(dog)` and `(RSVP random text)`, and ignore `cat`.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoAcHc/2)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\([^()]*(?:RSVP|§)[^()]*\)`. `(dog)` won't match, it has neither `§` nor `RSVP`.

Comment: Aww thank you again! Sorry I couldn't make it work on my own try..

Comment: It is just the same, just you need `(` and `)`, all escaped outside square brackets and non-escaped inside brackets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please tell me how can I target all of this `(RSVP 1111())`? Is there a way to set this kind exception? It can have multiple nested parenthesis inside such as `(RSVP (a)(b)(1))`.

Comment: No if you need any nesting level support. Besides, it will be difficult to decide where `RSVP` must be checked, on the first nested level or in all of them. Better [extract all substrings between nested parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses) and then check if they contain the necessary text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How about if it's always in the first level, is that possible? Anyway, thanks very much for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://regex101.com/r/FvLHWM/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Aww you're a legend sir! Thank you very much! ^_^